# Tagging a previous git commit on remote and branching local version

Tags: git

Here's the situation:

1. I previously committed code to the remote repository (master version)
2. I've since made changes to the local version but have not committed
3. I would like to tag the remote version with a version number, branch the and tag local (uncommitted) version as dev or something like that before committing

How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do it:

```
$ git status .
[...]
#    modified:  README.txt
[...]

# the following will create a tag on the last commit 
#  (the one already pushed to the remote)
$ git tag -a "v0.12" -m "version 0.12"

# send the tag to the remote
$ git push --tags

# create a new branch 'dev' and immediately switch to it
$ git checkout -b "dev"

# commit the modified files to the new branch
$ git commit -m "updated README for new 'dev'-version" README.txt

# push the new branch to the remote
$ git push
```